# Python: Variable inside a Variable-Name

Tags: python, variables

I am very new to python and programming in general. I am currently building a cocktail-mixer and also do the coding from ground up!
My program fortunately works, since I am just adding simple commands after the other... but this is limiting me extremely in scaling my project!
So here is my problem:

I started of to test my electronics with just two cocktails.
So in various functions in my program I have something like this (example)

```
def Cocktail1():
    Pump1Amount (< this is a variable) = 100 * Cocktail1Ingredient1 (<this is a variable too)
    Pump2Amount = 100 * Cocktail1Ingredient2
    Pump3Amount = 100 * Cocktail1Ingredient3

def Cocktail2():
    Pump1Amount (< this is a variable) = 100 * Cocktail2Ingredient1 (<this is a variable too)
    Pump2Amount = 100 * Cocktail2Ingredient2
    Pump3Amount = 100 * Cocktail2Ingredient3

and so on...
```

Now I wanted to add more Cocktails and more Pumps! But to accomplish this with my previous code, I would need to do A LOT of repetition and changing hundreds of single digits in all the functions... I want 12 Cocktails, 12 Pumps, so that already equals to 144 different segments of code... and then situations like I showed exist in my program a few times!

So what I was thinking is something like this:

```
def CocktailX():
    ChosenCocktail = X (<this is a variable that is set with pressing a button)
    Pump1Amount = 100 * CocktailXIngredient1
    Pump2Amount = 100 * CocktailXIngredient2
```

You see what I am talking about? I want to refer to a variable by using a general variable in that variable-name!

As I said, I am really new and therefore don´t know all the important terminology and everything! So please explain your answers to me like you would do it to a fourth-grader :D Thank you so much in advance!!!!

Comment: This is a pretty clear case. You need to learn about object oriented programming and how to write your own classes in Python.

Comment: @jpp the formatting problems likely stem from writing the question. I don't think this question is too bad for a first one.

Comment: @timgeb, thanks for fixing. I hope that's the case.. still not clear with "pressing a button"...

Comment: You don't necessarily need to write your own classes for this. To begin with, you should [learn about dictionaries and other built-in data structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html). You could for example create a dictionary in which you store the ingredients for each cocktail which you can look up by its name.

Comment: as timgeb said, you should re-structure your code to use OOP, what you are trying to do becomes easier with that.

Comment: @mkrieger1 true, but being smug and taunting authors of classes that the same could have been achieved with a dict plus some methods comes after learning to write classes. :D

Comment: what exactly are `CocktailXIngredient1` ?  Where did you declare them?  Do your functions return a value?  Do they call functions which cause something to happen?  For instance, if I run a program that calls, `Cocktail1()`, what happens?

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments! I´ve looked up dictionaries and they will definitely help me at some points! But I honestly don´t really see how dictionaries can help me here! 

As far from what I´ve read, I have to call a value from a dictionary by naming the dic and the key. But how is that different than just naming a predefined variable? Or is there a way to place variable-names inside a dictionary?

@e.s. CocktailXIngredient1 is just my example of a Variable (Cocktail1Ingredient1) using another vairable (x)
I´ve declared all variables manually and the functions sets new ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is possible to *compute* variable names in many languages (including Python), the common case of a number of analogous variables distinguished by a numeric label (an *index*) is handled by an **array** (in Python called `list`).  You can write `PumpAmounts[0]` and `CocktailIngredients[3][5]`—the latter conceptually is a variable with two indices and physically is a `list` of `list`s.

The important bit is that an index is an *expression*—which can be a *literal* (`a[1]`), a variable (`a[x]`), or a (more complicated) computation (`a[b[2*getHalfIndex(foo)]]`).  These choices also let you treat all the elements of a list in a loop that changes the index, although the normal way to simply visit each element in Python doesn’t use indices:

```
for elem in array:
  foo(elem, ...)
```

PS—I had this same question when I started programming: the first reference I had (for a different language) covered functions much more than syntax, so I didn’t know arrays existed.

Comment: Thank you so much! This also seems like a useful tip for future programming! But also here: how can this help me?

What is the difference in using PumpAmount1 - a variable i declared before and have to copy and paste - to using PumpAmount[0]? Don´t I need to copy PumpAmount[0] also over and over again? Or can I use a variable (for example X) inside what you´ve proposed? Like PumpAmount[X]

Comment: @AskerBuoi: Edited to address your question.